# Is it fine to use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I am building an application with one Activity `MainActivity` which consists of two fragments. And I came across with many tutorials that use `FrameLayout` as the parent container for the fragment layout.

However, I came to know that I can still use `LinearLayout` as parent container of the fragment and it works perfectly fine (so far).

My question, is there any side effect(s) of not using `FrameLayout` as the parent container for the fragment layout?

If there isn't, then what is the advantage of using `FrameLayout` over `LinearLayout` (or other possible layout) as the parent container of the fragment layout.

Comment: can you post the code that you use `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout`

Comment: You should change the title, it says fragmentlayout...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Fragments` themselves are rendered just like any `View`, so you can use whatever parent `ViewGroup` you would like depending on how you want your layout to look.  This means there's no inherent benefit of `LinearLayout` vs `FrameLayout` tied to `Fragments` at all.

The main difference between `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout` is that `Views` stack within a `FrameLayout`.

In other words, if you want your `Fragments` to potentially overlap, use a `FrameLayout`.  If you want them displayed linearly, use a `LinearLayout`.  If it's a fullscreen `Fragment` then it likely doesn't matter which you choose.

Comment: That's a simple and perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

FrameLayout is more efficient than LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.Because it is the simplest base layout,and there are no association between child layouts.
FrameLayout is suitable for stack-up views,and often used with ScrollView.

Answer (score 5):

It's Perfectly fine. You can use. But, in general :

**LinearLayout** is used for aligning views one by one vertically or horizontally. so that multiple child views can arrange accordingly.

**FrameLayout** is used to load views one above another. so `FrameLayout` use to hold single child view because it is difficult to manage multiple view in `FrameLayout`. For Ex. if you want to use single `CardView` then `FrameLayout` is perfect.